# Merge rows with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

So I made a large csv file with information about car models, there are some rows like this:

```
101 | land rover 90 2.5 td 4X4 | 148 | 1 | 0.68 | 0.0068 | 0 | 35 
101 | land rover 90 2.5 td 4X4 | 148 | 1 | 0.68 | 0.0068 | 9 | 0
```

I want to merge these lines on the second column (name), the output has to look like this:

```
101 | land rover 90 2.5 td 4X4 | 148 | 1 | 0.68 | 0.0068 | 9 | 35
```

I tried making a pandas dataframe and using the groupby function but it doesn't seem to be working. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `df.groupby('name').max()`?

Comment: You could potentially loop through the rows and concatenate as you move through, storing the results into an array that you then declare as the Series in a Dataframe. If it's a relatively large set of data, it may not be the best option as far as performance, but it will get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([
            [101,'land rover 90 2.5 td 4X4', 148, 1, 0.68, 0.0068, 0, 35 ], 
            [101, 'land rover 90 2.5 td 4X4', 148, 1, 0.68, 0.0068, 9, 0],  
        ], 
        columns=["col1","col2","col3","col4","col5","col6","col7","col8"])

df_new = df.groupby('col1', as_index=False).max()
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to sum() the 2 columns after grouping them, this didn't work. max() did the job.